# Rank-2 update for Cholesky factor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, cholesky-decomposition

What is the most efficient way to update Cholesky factor if we have rank 2  update to the initial matrix?

In other words:
Given a positive-definite matrix *A* where $$ A = L^T L , A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$$ and its computed Cholesky factor *L* we want to compute Cholesky decomposition of rank-2 update:
$$ 
A + M, M \in \mathbb{R}^{n}{n}
$$
where M is a rank-2 matrix.